# Find the value of k such that P(X<k)=1/3 With additional information in description

Tags: probability, integration

f(x)= 2(x-1)/3 in the interval 1<x<2 and 4-x/3 in the intervals 2<x<4 and 0 otherwise there are 3 f(x) and I am familiar with finding the unknown variable k when there is one f(x) but in this problem there is 2 main ones the 0 is useless but I don't know which equation to fill in the numbers I tries both but they were wrong the answers spouse to be 2 but I don't know how to get it . Any help is really appreciated! This is in the topic continuous random variables in statistics and probbaility.[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please ask the question in a different way? Where did the function come from? Where does the randomness come in?

Comment: Theose are the functions there are two functions  2(x-1)/3 in the interval 1<x<2 and 4-x/3 in the intervals 2<x<4 that's what is given to me at the top of the question it is a 3 part question I dont jhave a teacher to ask so I am very confused

Comment: OKay... but where does the probability come in? Is f a density function?

Comment: I added pictures on how the question looks maybe that will be more clear yes it is a density function

Comment: I whent throught it again and its PDF but what does that change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $f(1)=0$ and $f(2)=\frac{2}{3}$. Hence for $1<x\leq2$, the region under the graph of $y=f(x)$ is a triangle with area $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$. Hence $k=2$.

Comment: How did you get the f(2)

Comment: replace $x$ with $2$ in both expressions. They both give you $\frac{2}{3}$, and assuming that the $f$ is continuous, that means that $f(2)=2$.

Comment: But how do you know to replace it with 2 not 1 or 3 or 4?

Comment: I tried $2$ to see whether or not we would need to consider values of $k$ bigger than $2$, since then the area under $f$ would have to include both 'bits' of $f$. It just so happened that $2$ worked nicely.

Comment: Owww i see so i take the number which connets the two functions to see which one to take but what if the answer was 3 how do you know which function to consider if it doesn't fit perfectly

Comment: If $k>2$ then we would find that out because the area under the first bit of $f$ would be less than $\frac{1}{3}$, so in order to make up the area to $\frac{1}{3}$, we would have to include some of the other bit of $f$.

Comment: Owww i see thank you very much!

Comment: you're very welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

For $x\in[1,\,2]$, the CDF is $\int_1^xf(t)dt=\tfrac13(x-1)^2$, so $P(X\le2)=\tfrac13$. You needn't consider the CDF on $(2,\,4]$, as clearly $k=2$.

Comment: I am sorry but i am confused how did you get these numbers?

Comment: @maryjames The support is $[1,\,4]$, so I just evaluated the CDF at $x=2$, where the PDF's formula changes, so I could see whether $k<2$, $k=2$ or $k>2$.

Comment: But when I replace x on both the equations it equals with 2 it equals to 2/3

Comment: @maryjames I bet you're evaluating the PDF there instead of the CDF.

Comment: I whent throught it again and its PDF but what does that change ?

Comment: @maryjames Well, $P(X\le k)=\int_1^kf(t)dt$, so the question at hand is about the CDF.

Comment: I am sorry it takes a bit time for me to understand but how did you figure out the difference between PDF and CDF. I understand how to get this specific answer but I am talking in general

Comment: @marynames In general $P(X\le k)$ is the CDF at $k$.

Comment: Owww i seee thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

So if you check this $f$ given would be a density function for a random variable $X$ What this would mean $$\int_1^4 f(x)dx = 1$$ So what you want is to find a $k$ s.t. $$\int_1^k f(x)dx \le 1/3$$ Now the form of $f$ is given. So if $f$ was defined in the same way over the entire domain then you could replace $f$ with that definition and performed an integration with $k$ being solved as an unknown. However as $f$ is defined over 2 intervals you should take care and take 2 cases. One when $k$ belongs to the first and the other when $k$ belongs to the second and proceed in the manner similar to if there was only a single equation. Ofcourse since $f$ is a density function the value of $k$ would be unique. So you have to eliminate one of the choices of $k$ you get from considering the 2 equations using the definition of the function.

Comment: aw okay thank you:)